# How do I use RVM to create a gemset of three gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I want to play around with three similar Ruby gems called 'yahoofinance' 'yahoo-finance' and 'yahoo_stock'. I'm interested in how each gem works with Yahoo Finance. So I start with creating an rvm gemset,

```
[sandbox]$ rvm gemset create finance
'finance' gemset created (/Users/milktrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@finance).
```

Then I use it,

```
[sandbox]$ rvm gemset use finance
Now using gemset 'finance'
```

Then I attached it to a ruby,

```
[sandbox]$ rvm 1.9.2-head@finance
```

Then I installed the three gems above,

```
[sandbox]$ gem install yahoo-finance yahoofinance yahoo_stock
Successfully installed yahoo-finance-0.0.2
Successfully installed yahoofinance-1.2.2
Successfully installed yahoo_stock-1.0.2
3 gems installed
.
.
.
Installing RDoc documentation for yahoo_stock-1.0.2...
```

Now I'm incorrectly assuming I can require all three gems in an irb sesssion. Only one of them returns true.

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > require 'yahoofinance'
=> true
```

While the other two throw errors.

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > require 'yahoo-finance'
LoadError: no such file to load -- yahoo-finance

ruby-1.9.2-head > require 'yahoo_stock'  
SyntaxError: ...
```

Is there a problem with the gems or my installation?

NOTE: I am foggy about the rvm gemset use command, and it's probably not being used correctly above.

```
[sandbox]$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.7)
rake (0.8.7)
yahoo-finance (0.0.2)
yahoo_stock (1.0.2) 
yahoofinance (1.2.2)
```

Comment: What is the output of `gem list` in this gemset?

Comment: @Matchu, I put it into the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially hit the same errors you did, so it's not environment.

The issue with `yahoo-finance` is that it must be required as `yahoo_finance`.

The issue with `yahoo_stock` is a syntax error, indicating that the file is being loaded, but not interpreted correctly. Upon inspecting the [Github project's changelog](https://github.com/nas/yahoo_stock/blob/master/History.txt), we see that this syntax error in `history.rb` for Ruby 1.9.1 was fixed in version 1.0.5, but the version in [the central gem repository](http://rubygems.org) is 1.0.2. Turns out that the gem's owner now calls the gem [`nas-yahoo_stock`](http://rubygems.org/gems/nas-yahoo_stock), so running `gem install nas-yahoo_stock` should resolve that issue.

Comment: Very illuminating. This solves another mystery in that I was able to require 'yahoo-finance' previously but only because I had made a typo by putting in require 'yahoo_finance' which happens to be not a typo. I suppose I need to contact these gem maintainers and alert them of these issues. Thanks much.

Comment: @Milktrader: Glad to help :) As far as contacting goes, I'm pretty sure that the `yahoo-finance` naming convention wasn't a mistake, even if it's unexpected. Dashes in the gem name and underscores in Ruby file is a fairly common convention, even if I'm not sure I totally agree with it. For `yahoo_stock`, I'm not sure he'll change anything, since the name change was intentional but he still needs to support old references to `yahoo_stock`, though it'd be nice if he could include a deprecation notice on the [RubyGems.org entry](http://rubygems.org/gems/yahoo_stock). Regardless, give it a go :)